# access private (Class extensions) members in subclass

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a 3rd party class that contain the following extention:

```
@interface BaseClass ()
{
   int privateMember;
}
@end
```

i've created my own subclass:

```
  @interface SubClass : BaseClass {
  }
  @end
```

is there a way to access privateMember in SubClass?

---

EDIT:
actual code

GPUImageMovie.m: (base class)

```
@interface GPUImageMovie ()
{
    BOOL audioEncodingIsFinished, videoEncodingIsFinished;
    GPUImageMovieWriter *synchronizedMovieWriter;
    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef coreVideoTextureCache;
    AVAssetReader *reader;
}
```

MultiTrackGPUImageMovie.h (subclass)

```
@interface MultiTrackGPUImageMovie : GPUImageMovie {
}
...
@end
```

MultiTrackGPUImageMovie.m (subclass)

```
 - (void)processMovieFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)movieSampleBuffer forTarget:(int)targetToSendIdx {
 ...
 CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,       coreVideoTextureCache, movieFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight,   GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &texture);
 ...
}
```

give error
 Use of undeclared identifier 'coreVideoTextureCache'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the 'private' member has been declared. If there **wasn't** the `@private` keyword before it, i. e. it was really

```
@interface BaseClass ()
{
    int privateMember;
}
@end
```

and **not**

```
@interface BaseClass ()
{
    @private
    int privateMember;
}
@end
```

then you can easily reference this instance variable simply by using its name - the default access scope for instance variables is protected, i. e. not accessible outside the class, but accessible from subclasses.

However, if it **was** declared as `private`, you'll have to fall back using the runtime functions; in your subclass, declare and implement this method:

```
- (void *)pointerForIvarWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [name UTF8String]);
    return ((char *)self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
int ivarPtr;
ivarPtr = *(int *)[self pointerForIvarWithName:@"privateMember"];
```

Edit: so it seems the member you're trying to access is in a class extension and not public in the header file. In this case, you can go for the 2nd solution only (although it's not advised to do so).

Comment: Ewwww...  Do not get the pointer and use it like that. Fragile and way too much code.  Just stick the class extension in a header imported prior to the @implementation and also imported into the subclass .m files.  That is one of the two main reasons why we designed class extensions as they were.

Comment: @bbum I didn't say that's not fragile, I was too tired to explain to OP why is this not good idea (and why it's not a good idea to access private members.) :) I only provided an answer strictly to the question he or she asked.

Comment: no, there is not @private, but are you sure i can just use its name in the subclass?  i get "Use of undeclared identifier 'coreVideoTextureCache" when i try

Comment: @amit you're doing something wrong, please post some actual code.

Comment: @H2CO3 added original code. how can i make MultiTrackGPUImageMovie aware of coreVideoTextureCache when its not in the header file?

Comment: @H2CO3 Fair enough -- given that he has the source to the abstract super, why not just add the property directly?

Comment: `object_getIvar` seems to be a tad safer

Comment: @Daij-Djan Except that it doesn't work for types where `sizeof(T) > sizeof(id)`.

Comment: ah ok :) well I only need an id ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me it is impossible to use the default @protected ivar from the class extension in the subclass like said the the accepted answer, **when the class extension is in the `.m` file**.

So here is how I could solve this issue without using the runtime API (which should not be used in such a manner).

---

They are implemented, also for the subclass `SubClass. You can not access them, because the declaration ist not visible to the subclass.

The subclass does not have access to the *class extension* `@interface BaseClass ()` of the `BaseClass`.

You have 2 options:

Copy

> ```
> @interface BaseClass () {
>     int privateMember;
> }
> @end
> ```

to every subclass. Yes it is the *class extension* of the `BaseClass` inside the `.m` file of the `SubClass`.

**OR**

Create a `.h` file without a `.m`, only with the class extension code (like above) inside. Import that to the `BaseClass` and the `SubClass`.